# C# SqlCommand initialization string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm working on a C# program that someone else wrote. At some point, I encountered

```
SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("pr_upiteminvent", connString);
```

According  to the C# API, that first parameter in the SqlCommand constructor should be a query, but the person who developed this program used "pr_upiteminvent" instead. Any ideas what it might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it's probably the name of a stored procedure. That's fine, so long as you then have:

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

(I hope that the real code has appropriate `using` statements as well, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True");    
connString.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("exec pr_upiteminvent", connString);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connString.Close();
```

Assuming that it is stored procedure you have to also use.

`using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Answer (score 1):

It is a stored procedure. There is a command type parameter you can set.